# Query data from previous row and update current row

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table on which some data is missing, so I have to replace the missing data by the data of the day before.

I wanted to do a SQL update to solve this issue.

In case the following ***criteria*** is met -> if ID1 is in **set(a1,a2,a3)** AND **TYPE Is MISSING**

The variables **"Amount"** a/b will have an absurd value

We will then take the Amount a/b value of the row of the previous day, where ID1 and ID2 are the same as the one of the row where the ***criteria*** is met.

So here ID1 and ID2 are equal to a1 and b1 respectively, we look for a1 and b1 the previous day (10/03/2021) and get the amount 28.45/29.46 that we use to replace the false amount 454848.25/548926.36.

We also copy **Type** value.

| ID1 | ID2 | Amount a | Amount b | day | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | 28.45 | 29.46 | 10/03/2021 | Out |
| a2 | b1 | 36.84 | 37.88 | 10/03/2021 | In |
| a1 | b1 | **454848.25** | **548926.36** | 11/03/2021 | **/*MISSING*/** |

Goal:

| ID1 | ID2 | Amount a | Amount b | day | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | b1 | 28.45 | 29.46 | 10/03/2021 | Out |
| a2 | b1 | 36.84 | 37.88 | 10/03/2021 | In |
| a1 | b1 | **28.45** | **29.46** | 11/03/2021 | **Out** |

My table consists of thousands of rows, but it's the idea

I tried to use lag and SQL update, but did not succeed.

Comment: Please TAG your RDBMS.  What happens if there's no row for the previous day, is that possible?

Comment: hello thanks for the answer, I use it on SAS and I don't know what RDBMS it is, also no it's not possible to have no row for the previous day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just sort by the keys and date and then use the `lag` function to look one row back. Maybe you already tried this, but used the `lag` only inside the `if type is missing` block. This won't help you as noted in the [documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/vdmmlcdc/8.1/lefunctionsref/n0l66p5oqex1f2n1quuopdvtcjqb.htm)

> Storing values at the bottom of the queue and returning values from
> the top of the queue occurs only when the function is executed. An
> occurrence of the LAG n function that is executed conditionally stores
> and return values only from the observations for which the condition
> is satisfied.

Instead, compute the lag in every row, not just in those satisfying the condition.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by ID1 ID2 day;
run;

data want;
  set have;
  by ID1 ID2;
  lag_amount_a = lag(amount_a);
  lag_amount_b = lag(amount_b);
  lag_day = lag(day);
  lag_type = lag(type);
  if ID1 in ("a1", "a2", "a3") and missing(type) then do;
    // check if row before matches ID1, ID2 and day - 1
    if not first.ID2 and day = lag_day + 1 then do;
      amount_a = lag_amount_a;
      amount_b = lag_amount_b;
      type = lag_type;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is met, replace absurd values by proper missing values and assign a pointer to the day before.
Then lookup using the initial table.

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter='|';
input ID1 $ ID2 $ Amount_A Amount_B day :ddmmyy10. type $;
format day ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
a1|b1|28.45|29.46|10/03/2021|Out
a2|b1|36.84|37.88|10/03/2021|In
a1|b1|454848.25|548926.36|11/03/2021|
;

data stage1;
set have;
if ID1 in ('a1','a2','a3') and type = "" then do;
    Amount_A = .;
    Amount_B = .;
    _date = day - 1;
    type = "Out";
end;
format _date ddmmyy10.;
run;

data want;
    if 0 then set have;
    if _n_ = 1 then do;
        declare hash h(dataset:'have');
        h.definekey('ID1','ID2','day');
        h.definedata('Amount_A','Amount_B');
        h.definedone();
    end;
    
    set stage1;
    rc = h.find(key:ID1, key:ID2, key: _date);
    drop rc _date;
run;
```

```
ID1 ID2 Amount_A Amount_B    day      type
a1  b1  28.45     29.46   10/03/2021  Out
a2  b1  36.84     37.88   10/03/2021  In
a1  b1  28.45     29.46   11/03/2021  Out
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like simple LOCF.  Thanks @kermit for data HAVE.

```
data have;
   infile datalines delimiter='|';
   input ID1 $ ID2 $ Amount_A Amount_B day :ddmmyy10. type $;
   format day ddmmyy10.;
   datalines;
a1|b1|28.45|29.46|10/03/2021|Out
a2|b1|36.84|37.88|10/03/2021|In
a1|b1|454848.25|548926.36|11/03/2021|
;;;;
   run;
proc sort data=have;
   by id1 id2;
   run;
data LOCF;
   update have(obs=0) have;
   by id1 id2;
   output;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]